# Type error with rank-n types and lenses

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, higher-rank-types

I have a simple polymorphic datatype `Foo`

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

data Foo c = 
    Foo {
        _bar :: c,
        _baz :: c,
        _quux :: c
    }   

makeLenses ''Foo
```

The generated lenses are, of course, polymorphic in `c`. The type from GHCi is:

```
*Main> :t bar
bar :: Functor f => (c0 -> f c0) -> Foo c0 -> f (Foo c0)
```

I made a datatype `Blah` to wrap around the lens. This works fine in simple cases (with the `RankNTypes` extension, of course):

```
data Blah = Blah (forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c)

orange :: Blah
orange = Blah bar
```

But anything slightly more complicated doesn't work, for example

```
cheese :: [Blah]
cheese = map Blah [bar]
```

This last piece of code gives an error from GHC:

```
    Couldn't match type ‘(c0 -> f0 c0) -> Foo c0 -> f0 (Foo c0)’
                  with ‘forall c (f :: * -> *).
                        Functor f =>
                        (c -> f c) -> Foo c -> f (Foo c)’
    Expected type: ((c0 -> f0 c0) -> Foo c0 -> f0 (Foo c0)) -> Blah
      Actual type: (forall c. Lens' (Foo c) c) -> Blah
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘Blah’
    In the expression: map Blah [bar]
```

It seems like the `forall c f .` has disappeared from `‘(c0 -> f0 c0) -> Foo c0 -> f0 (Foo c0)’` but I don't understand why.

Why does this not compile, and what can I do to get something like this to work?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I could give a correct enough explanation for why to warrant a full answer, but it seems to be a scoping problem with `Blah`.  If you move the `forall c.` outside of the constructor as `data Blah = forall c. Blah (Lens' (Foo c) c)` then `map Blah` will typecheck, but `map Blah [bar]` won't.  If you expand the `Lens'` type and manually do `data Blah = forall c f. Functor f => Blah ((c -> f c) -> Foo c -> f (Foo c))` then you have `:t map Blah` as `Functor f => [(c -> f c) -> Foo c -> f (Foo c)] -> [Blah]` and `:t [bar, baz]` as `[(c -> f c) -> Foo c -> f (Foo c)]`...

Comment: ... but it can't unify the `Functor` constraint in `map Blah [bar, baz]`.  I believe this is because the `Blah` constructor is hiding too much from the type checker (essentially), so it can't figure out how to incorporate the `Functor` constraint.  If the lens type were unconstrained then it might actually work.

Comment: The only way I can get anything to type-check is to add type parameters to `Blah` as `data Blah f c where Blah :: Functor f => ((c -> f c) -> Foo c -> f (Foo c)) -> Blah f c`, then you can do `map Blah [bar, baz]` and have the type `Functor f => [Blah f c]`, but this doesn't mean that there isn't a way to hide those type variables.  The important one here is `f` I think, because the `Functor` constraint.  The compiler has to pick an instance for `Functor`, but has no way of picking just one, so it fails the type check.

Comment: You want `[bar]` to have type `[forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c]`, but it actually has the type `Functor f => [(c0 -> f c0) -> Foo c0 -> f (Foo c0)]`. You *can* force `[bar]` to have the former type, by simply specifying that type signature - but you need to enable ImpredicativeTypes. The same goes for `map Blah` - it also has an impredictive type, so you will also need to specify it manually. For example; `bar' :: [forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c]; bar' = [bar] ; mapBlah :: [forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c] -> [Blah]; mapBlah = map Blah` typechecks, and so will `mapBlah bar'`.

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't recommend using impredictive types - you will have to write a type signature for every impredictive type and it doesn't give you much power.

Comment: @user2407038: Could you put that into an answer? It addresses the question and will be easier for people to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `[bar]` to have type `[forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c]`, but it actually has the type `forall f c . Functor f => [(c -> f c) -> Foo c -> f (Foo c)]`. The compiler infers the latter type signature because it is *predicative*. You can find [resources](http://blog.solaris.bytelabs.org/articles/2008/08/10/predicative-vs-impredicative-polymorphism-and-type-reconstruction) on the technical details of (im)predictive types. In short, type inference is undecidable in the presence of impredictive types - so type signatures become mandatory - so by default they are not permitted. An impredictive type is one where a `forall` occurs inside a type constructor (like `[]`).

You can force `[bar]` to have the former type, by simply specifying that type signature and enabling `ImpredicativeTypes`. The same goes for `map Blah` - it also has an impredictive type, so you will also need to specify it manually.

```
bar' :: [forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c]
bar' = [bar] 

mapBlah :: [forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c] -> [Blah]
mapBlah = map Blah
```

Then the following typechecks:

```
> mapBlah bar'
```

or even

```
> (map Blah :: [forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c] -> [Blah]) 
    ([bar] :: [forall c . Lens' (Foo c) c])
```

In fact, the deal with the problem of impredictive types, `lens` includes the module [`Control.Lens.Reified`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.2/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html) which declares newtypes for all the common lens types so that you can have lenses in containers. This actually won't help you in this particular use case, because you also want the `c` in `Lens' (Foo c) c` to be bound inside the list constructor, but it is useful in general.

Comment: It's "impredicative" — not "impredictive". From the word "predicate".

Comment: To be pedantic, it's not impredicativity that hurts inference (in theory) but higher-ranked types. Inference for rank-2 types is impractical and it's undecidable for rank-3 and above. In practice, impredicativity wrecks type inference in Haskell because it's integrated poorly. There are other type systems with more organic handling of impredicative types, e. g. HMF, HML or MLF.